# Styling for responsive HTML email - attribute="x" vs. style="attribute:x;"

Tags: html-table, html-email

When styling tables for emails (or for any project), what is the significance of:

```html
<table cellpadding="10px">
```

over:

```html
<table style="padding:10px;">
```

Comment: To insert code in a question use the code insert button indicated by `{}`

Comment: In general they deprecated a lot of `attribute="..."` in favor of using style, either in-line or using separate css file.

Comment: `cellpadding` is deprecated, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#attr-cellpadding

Comment: Thank you for answers - little daunting - hope I'm thanking everyone and in the right place - feel very lost inside this Code Store (like I'm looking up all around me at racks of code 100 feet tall and I'm the little dot in the middle of it all :))

Comment: This is taken from a tutorial 'How to code responsive Emails" from Litmus which is what I was following.

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin: 0; padding: 0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

Comment: Is this to cater for the different clients that either do or do not support the different style input methods? If so, why leave out the width="100%"? Which I would think to put after cellspacing="0"

Answer (score 1):

In email you would use `<table cellpadding="10">`.

In the case of what you posted, some email clients will ignore `attribute="10px"` completely, which is why you would use `attribute="10"` instead.

The problem with inline styles is Outlook tends to ignore them. It's selective on what it ignores.

This style might be deprecated in HTML 5, but email clients like Outlook 2007-2019 do not follow best practices.

Email development is not web development. It's a different style and set of rules you need to follow for optimal results.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - tis daunting up in here, so I hope I'm putting this thanks in the right place